# Optimization challenges (currently active or soon to begin)

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, heuristics, metaheuristics

I am looking for an optimization challenge for an intern (such as ROADEF Challenge, Gecco competitions, or CEC competitions) active during summer 2023 (ideally July - September). Longer competitions or "small" competitions within conferences are ok.

I'll be thankful for any tips!

Answer (score 3):

Lehigh University Modeling and Optimization: Theory and Applications (MOPTA) program.

[15th AIMMS-MOPTA Optimization Modeling Competition](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Emopta/competition)

Teams must consist of at most 3 students. An individual student working by themself might be at a disadvantage.

Details are at
[15th AIMMS-MOPTA Optimization Modeling Competition:
Planning Electric Vehicle Charging Stations](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Emopta/mopta2023/MOPTA2023_Competition.pdf)